# "Undefined is not a function" error when using a KendoUI custom download containing only the grid with asp.mvc wrapper and Datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a custom Kendo download that contains only the grid in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that uses razor for generating the grid and also uses server side code for generating the grid data.  I have selected the applicable fields in the custom download page that generates these scripts: 
[image: kendoScripts]

I have included the scripts and css in the header tag of my _layout.cshtml page:
[image: renderedScripts]

The code that calls the grid is bound to a simple model with two string properties(name, desc) and calls a controller action:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridStandAloneTest.Models.GridModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("GetPeople", "Home")
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false))
.Columns(x => 
{
    x.Bound(c => c.Name);
    x.Bound(c => c.Salary); 
}))
```

When the page renders the grid is visible, but the controller action never gets called.  I also get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the console.  However, if I click on a column it does call the controller action, but then it returns it to a new tab with the JSON data under the URL.

The controller code looks like :

```
    public ActionResult GetPeople([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest DataSource)
    {
        var people = new List<GridStandAloneTest.Models.GridModel>()
        {
            new GridStandAloneTest.Models.GridModel(){Name = "Jon", Salary = "50,000"},
            new GridStandAloneTest.Models.GridModel(){Name = "Joe", Salary = "100,000"}
        };

        DataSourceResult result = people.ToDataSourceResult(DataSource);

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `Batch(true)` and `ServerOperation(false)` to see if that does anything?  The only other thing I could think of.

Comment: I tried that as well.  Do you think I could be improperly building the package?  I am about to go through the docs again to make sure I didn't miss any steps(like the jquery version you noticed) just to make sure.

Comment: Maybe try using the full build - not your custom one, just to see if you still get the error?

Comment: So I tried running it with only the common css file, jquery-1.9.1,  kendo.all.min.js, and kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js and I got the same error, but I also added a date-picker to the page which was able to render correctly, albeit the style looked a little off, but there were no errors.

Comment: I can't remember if the screenshot (with the dark background) was there before or not, but I still don't see the `aspnetmvc.min.js` in there.  Also, I just noticed jQuery is *after* Kendo - jQuery needs to come first.

Comment: In the comment above I listed them in the explicit order I have them added right now, which is Jquery, kendo.all., kendo.aspnetmvc,  I have not edited the pictures from the original post.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read that - my apologies.

Comment: No worries.  I'm actually going to start from the beginning one more time and go through the tutorial to make sure I'm not missing any steps.  It seems odd that I cant add all and get it to work.  It makes me think it's something I'm doing and not an issue with how I'm creating the custom build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74837/discussion-between-codekiller-and-mmillican).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least 2 problems:

1. You're including jQuery multiple times.  Make sure jQuery is included only once or the grid js will break.
2. When reproducing I noticed that it seems the Pager.js file wasn't included in the custom build even through I'd selected it.  The error I was getting was an *`instanceof` is not a function* which pointed to where it was checking for Pager code.

Comment: Oddly I used the CDN to explicitly grab the correct scripts rather than the custom downloader and that seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're including `jQuery 1.7.1`, and the latest versions of KendoUI requre `1.9.1+`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that the jQuery versions needed to be specific and messing with them, but I will double check and post back here with the results.

Comment: @codekiller - yes if you look at the Kendo documentation link I included you will see the jQuery version required for each version of Kendo

Comment: Updated the version to jQuery 1.9.1 and still got the same error, "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".  Also, I made sure the check the version in the console after the rebuild.

Comment: Even though you're using a custom build, you may still need to include the `kendo.aspnetmvc.js` file as well (after the Kendo custom js)

Comment: I selected that in the custom build, but just to make sure I also added it as another src file.  I still got the same result.